# pull and validate multiline strings from .txt file in Java?

Tags: java, string, loops, split

I have a .txt file with unknown size and content. I want to read in from file that customer data:

"NAME"-fName containing letters  secName can be letters and/or numbers
"AGE"-just numbers
"STUDENT.NO"-could be letters and numbers(set length)

Each piece of info is on a new line in .txt so first 3 lines=student 1 and next 3 student 2 etc.

End goal is to iterate over each student in blocks of 3, validate data and export to different file. How do I pull in first three lines and validate data for each of name, age, number.

```
    String fileName = "\\Users\\under\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\CA-Jan24\\students.txt";

    String line = null;
   
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));

        int i = 0;
        try {
            //print first 3 lines or all if file has less than 3 lines
            while(((line = br.readLine()) != null) && i < 3) {
                System.out.println(line);
                i++;
              
              //I get multi line String but dont know how to isolate eah line of info to put through if,        else statement 
            }   
        }
        finally {   
            br.close();         
        }

}
```

}

Comment: IMO, you should start by creating a method to turn a line from your file into a Student (deserialized) object, and a method to serialize a Student object back into text. This way you can do all of your validation logic on actual Java objects instead of text, and keep method (validation) logic out of (de)serialization.

Answer (score 0):

As ControlAltDel says, I think it is a very good approach.
Another faster way (not the best) to meet the requirements is the one attached below.
If the data does not go in groups of rows of 3, this solution does not work.
(The variable i is useful to know if I am reading the first name, last name, or age data.)

```
String fileName = "C:\\Users\\Usuario\\Documents\\test.txt";
    String line = null;
    
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName))) {
        int i = 0;
        //print first 3 lines or all if file has less than 3 lines
        while (((line = br.readLine()) != null)) {
            switch (i) {
                case 0:
                    System.out.println("line name = " + line + " is valid? " +  Pattern.matches("[a-zA-Z]+", line));
                    //store in temporary variable to proceed with dumping later
                    break;
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("line sec name = " + line + " is valid ? " + Pattern.matches("[a-zA-Z0-9]+", line));
                    //store in temporary variable to proceed with dumping later
                    break;
                default: {
                    System.out.println("line age = " + line + " is valid? " + Pattern.matches("\\d+", line));
                    //store in temporary variable to proceed with dumping later
                    i = 0; //Reset i
                }
            }
            i++;
            //I get multi line String but dont know how to isolate eah line of info to put through if,        else statement
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You’re allowed to call readLine() in other places besides the condition of a `while` loop.

Since you want to keep reading as long as we encounter a Name line in the file, not just any line, you should change this:

```
String line = null;
```

to this:

```
String nameLine;
```

(No need to initialize it, because the program will be assigning a value to it before any code attempts to use it.  The compiler will enforce that.)

In the loop, any time you encounter a Name line, you can safely assume it will be followed by an Age line and a Student line.  (At least, that’s my understanding;  if I’m wrong, feel free to correct me.)

```
try (BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(Path.of(fileName))) {
    while ((nameLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        String ageLine = br.readLine();
        String studentNumberLine = br.readLine();

        // Use nameLine, ageLine, and studentNumberLine to write to file
    }
}
```

Some minor notes:

- The modern way to open a file is with the [Path](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Path.html) and [Files](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html) classes.  In the event of a failure, the Files class will provide more informative exceptions than older classes like File and FileReader.
- Placing the BufferedReader in parentheses after `try` is known as a [try with resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement.  It causes the compiler to automatically generate a finally block that will close the BufferedReader.